# Consensus algorithm for Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, consensus, paxos, raft

I'm trying to implement a collaborative canvas in which many people can draw free-handly or with specific shape tools.
Server has been developed in Node.js and client with Angular1-js (and I am pretty new to them both).
I must use a consensus algorithm for it to show always the same stuff to all the users.

I'm seriously in troubles with it since I cannot find a proper tutorial its use. I have been looking and studying Paxos implementation but it seems like Raft is very used in practical.

Any suggestions? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Drawing could be done `<canvas>` with WebGL (Three.js), and connection can be established with [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). You can also look at [skiff algorithm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skiff-algorithm) ( - Abstract Node.js implementation of the Raft Consensus Algorithm)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey
I'm using WebSocket indeed, but having troubles with Consensus part. Do you know any tutorial or project in which skiff is used?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. You want to store data in a centralized location with some consistency. That's called a database. Tell clients to send their actions to some backend service somewhere, the backend service takes these + the existing data, gets some new data, stores that, and sends it back out to the connected clients.

Comment: @GManNickG it's requested to do it with a consensus protocol. Otherwise I would not ask for it :)

Comment: @JackLametta: Yikes. Well, invent a database (or e.g. use etcd, or reinvent etcd with Raft, and so on) and then pick up from where I started. And tell this person asking that this is a terrible way of developing software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing a distributed system is not an easy task[1], so I'd recommend using some existing strongly consistent one instead of implementing one from scratch. The usual suspects are [zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org), [consul](https://www.consul.io), [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/), [atomix/copycat](http://atomix.io). Some of them offer nodejs clients:

- https://github.com/alexguan/node-zookeeper-client
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/consul
- https://github.com/stianeikeland/node-etcd

I've personally never used any of them with nodejs though, so I won't comment on maturity of clients.

If you insist on implementing consensus on your own, then raft should be easier to understand — the paper is surprisingly accessible https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf. They also have some nodejs implementations, but again, I haven't used them, so it is hard to recommend any particular one. [Gaggle readme](https://github.com/ben-ng/gaggle) contains an example and [skiff has an integration test](https://github.com/pgte/skiff-algorithm/blob/master/tests/integration.js) which documents its usage.

Taking a step back, I'm not sure if the distributed consensus is what you need here. Seems like you have multiple clients and a single server. You can probably use a centralized data store. The problem domain is not really that distributed as well - shapes can be overlaid one on top of the other when they are received by server according to FIFO (imagine multiple people writing on the same whiteboard, the last one wins). The challenge is with concurrent modifications of existing shapes, by maybe you can fallback to last/first change wins or something like that.

Another interesting avenue to explore here would be [Conflict-free Replicated Data Types — CRDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type). Folks at github used them to implement collaborative "pair" programming in atom. See [the atom teletype blog post](http://blog.atom.io/2017/11/15/code-together-in-real-time-with-teletype-for-atom.html#conflict-free-editing), also [their implementation](https://github.com/atom/teletype#hacking) maybe useful, as collaborative editing seems to be exactly the problem you try to solve.

Hope this helps.

[1] Take a look at jepsen series https://jepsen.io/analyses where Kyle Kingsbury tests various failure conditions of distribute data stores.

Comment: Actually, I would need to replicate on EC2 the server to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Try reading [Understanding Paxos](https://understandingpaxos.wordpress.com/). It's geared towards software developers rather than an academic audience. For this particular application you may also be interested in the [Multi-Paxos Example Application](https://github.com/cocagne/multi-paxos-example) referenced by the article. It's intended both to help illustrate the concepts behind the consensus algorithm and it sounds like it's almost exactly what you need for this application. Raft and most Multi-Paxos designs tend to get bogged down with an overabundance of accumulated history that generates a new set of problems to deal with beyond simple consistency. An initial prototype could easily handle sending the full-state of the drawing on each update and ignore the history issue entirely, which is what the example application does. Later optimizations could be made to reduce network overhead.